# Aggregate results in MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a MySQL query. I have a DB table where i'm storing work sessions. It looks like this:

```
(int) id 
(int) user_id 
(timestamp) created_at 
(timestamp) stopped_at
```

I want to be able to retrieve the time spend for each date in seconds.
So far this is what my query looks like:

```
SELECT DATE(created_at) as date, TO_SECONDS(stopped_at) - TO_SECONDS(created_at) as time FROM work_sessions GROUP BY date;
```

This is close to my wanted result, but each 'date' will only contain the time for the first row in the group. Instead i would like every 'time' column for the date to be aggregated into one result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way

```sql
SELECT DATE(created_at) date, 
       SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, created_at, stopped_at)) time 
  FROM work_sessions 
 GROUP BY DATE(created_at);
```

**Note:** That's assuming that a work session can never span across a midnight.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aab0bd/2)** demo

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what i wanted.
Concerning sessions spanning over midnight i guess those would just be summed up with the start date?

Comment: That is right. Time difference for such rows will fall into `DATE(created_at)` group.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you wanted?

```
SELECT 
    DATE(created_at) as date, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(TO_SECONDS(stopped_at) - TO_SECONDS(created_at) SEPARATOR ", ") as time
FROM work_sessions 
GROUP BY date;
```